# Fetch row number MongoDB c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-compass

> I am fetching a single candidate exam result details after the
> examination. which is stored in mongodb using c# driver. The
> collection has TotalMarks field which is stored with marks obtained in
> that exam.
>
> Unfortunately the collection does not have the Rank Field because mark
> calculation is not done in order

**What I want to do is order the collection by totalmark and get the position(rank) of the candidate I am selecting.**

```
public ExamCandidateResult ExaminationGetCandidateResultStatus( Guid examinationId, Guid candidateId)
        {
            var con = new MongoClient(DBConnection.ExamConnectionString);
            var db = con.GetDatabase(ExamDB);
            var collection = db.GetCollection<ExamCandidateResult>("Examination");
            var filter = Builders<ExamCandidateResult>.Filter.Eq("ExaminationID", examinationId.ToString())
                       & Builders<ExamCandidateResult>.Filter.Eq("CandidateID", candidateId.ToString());
            var data = collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
            return data;
        }
```

> With this code I am fetching only the canidate details how can I fetch
> the rank(row) with it ?

Comment: I don't really understood what you need, but I guess you can reach the goal what you need at least via more powerful aggregation framework: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/. Please provide more details in order to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get the row number directly but You can use two queries, one to get the candidate and one to get the count of candidates who have more totalMarks than the desired candidate, and finally plus one count to get the rank of the candidate.

Comment: hey ,  can you check if [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69546620/mongodb-dynamic-row-number-creation) is possible ?